# yum error [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid

Tags: linux, yum

I have installed CentOS 6 in VM and trying to install few packages

`yum install` command gives the following error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
http://vault.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have checked many answers but none worked. Can anyone guide, please?

Comment: Wrong is http://vault.centos.org/6/os/x86_64 (follow the link, please) .... Example `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-610-64.repo` : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-O16nlOkftEo_lPHvQt5Df-ArvQtv4G_/view?usp=sharing ... and EPEL Vault   https://drive.google.com/file/d/12a0nQddW4m8bSCCIljoJp2-zw1ECNoaJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 14):

The problem is because the ca-certificate package is outdated on your system. To correct this problem :

```
wget https://vault.centos.org/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2020.2.41-65.1.el6_10.noarch.rpm --no-check-certificate
rpm -iU ca-certificates-2020.2.41-65.1.el6_10.noarch.rpm
```

Please keep in mind that CentOS 6 is no longer in production, and due to the changing landscape of security certificates, there is no guarantee this fix will work forever.

Comment: Do you know if that ca-certificates package which is for centos 6.10 can be used on 6.2 or other versions ?

Comment: @rtaranu just tested on CentOS 6.8 and works.

Comment: For any other poor soul stuck with obsolete versions of CentOS which won't connect to the interwebs anymore, check this out .. it worked for me

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/rhel-centos-6-openssl-client-compatibility-after-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration/161032/81